# Lapply on a list of arrays

Tags: r

I have a list which contains again multiple lists of arrays. The goal is to calculate the mean values of each of the arrays for the the third dimension.

So when the array is of the dimensions `c(54,71,360)` the resulting mean values should be a matrix of the dimensions `c(54,71)` for every single member of the lists.

Here is some code to reproduce sample data:

```
######################### create sample data ###########################
# create empty list
list1 <- list()

# fill the list with arrays
for (i in 1:10) {
  list1[[i]] <- array(sample(1:100, 600, replace=T), dim= c(54,71,360))
}

# create the big list
big_list <- list()
for (i in 1:8) {
  big_list[[paste0("list", i)]] <- list1
}
```

I can achieve it using a for loop:

```
######################## way to do it with for loop ####################
for (i in 1:length(big_list)) {
  for (j in 1:length(list1)) {
    big_list[[i]][[j]] <- apply(big_list[[i]][[j]], 1:2, mean, na.rm= T)
  }
}
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way using `lapply` in a nested way or something that leads to the same result by just using one or two lines.
I have struggled finding a way to combine the `lapply` command with `apply/sapply/etc.` inside so that the arrays inside the single lists are approached properly. I guess `lapply` is needed since I need the big lists of lists as outcome.

Anybody with an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will need the concept of *anonymous functions*. In essence, you declare custom made function in the middle of a `lapply`. This gives you the liberty of using indexing within lapply.

```
result = lapply(big_list, function(x) {
                           lapply(x, function(y) {
                                     apply(y, 1:2, mean, na.rm= T)
                                      }
                                  )
                           }
               )
```

Tough, I must say that at that point, lapplys are doing more harm to the clarity of the code than helping. So, I would actually stick to using `for`.

If you can remove the nested list structure and recreate it, it might be easier create codes with lapply. But that's beyond the question, since you mentioned you have to keep it.

Comment: JMenezes, thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for! When you put the code in one line, it does not look too unclear, so I prefer this over the ```for``` loop.

Maybe one thing to add: In your code above there is apparently one closing bracket to much. This worked for me: 
```big_list <- lapply(big_list, function(x) {lapply(x, function(y) {apply(y, 1:2, mean, na.rm= T)})})```

Comment: No worries. Corrected the brackets for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `purrr` and nested `map()`s, which are similar to `lapply`, but with clearer synthax

```
library(purrr)

map(1:8, ~map(1:10, ~ array(sample(1:100, 600, replace=T), dim= c(54,71,360))))
```

If you want you can keep using `lapply` the base R synthax for anonnymous functions in a similar fashion:

```
lapply(1:8, \(x) lapply(1:10, \(y) array(sample(1:100, 600, replace=T), dim= c(54,71,360))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond GuedesBF. The answer above does the job perfectly without any additional package.